# Is there a way to write the content (stored in a spark Dataframe) of images into files in parallel with pyspark?

Tags: azure, pyspark, serialization, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a Spark Dataframe which contains in every single row two items: a file name (with an extension, like for instance .jpg), and the content of the file in bytes.
I would like to write a process that takes each row of the Dataframe and converts the bytes to a '.jpg' image while I store it into an ADLS container.

Everything needs to run inside a Databricks cluster so I use pyspark in order to create the Dataframe, and I would like to make use of it to truncate those files into the destination.

However, I am having trouble when I use the azure-storage library to write those files by using it inside a map function. Like the following example, where the function `consume_row` uses the library to create the file and write the content like this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python?tabs=azure-ad#append-data-to-a-file):

```
results_rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: consume_row(row, ...))
```

It returns the following error:

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread._local' object

Has anyone tried to do anything similar to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was inside the function `consume_row`. We were using a variable to store the token for the API which, underneath, was using a Thread Local Python object to store the token itself, and this was not serializable by pickle to be sent to workers. So we just needed to pass the token to the function and everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

PySpark uses Python's `pickle` module for serialization, and certain objects (like `_thread._local` objects) cannot be pickled.

To achieve your goal, you need to mount your adls2 account and save the file.

Follow the steps below.

Here, I am mounting using the account key. You can also mount using a `SAS` token or `OAuth`.

```py
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<container_name>@<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/jadls2",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net":"<account_key>"})
```

Next, use the code below.

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

sample_data = [
    ("image1.jpg", image1_content),
    ("image2.jpg", image2_content)
]

columns = ["filename", "content"]
sample_df = spark.createDataFrame(sample_data, columns)

def consume_row(row):
    filename, content = row
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(content))
    image.save(f"/dbfs/mnt/jadls2/databricks/images/{filename}",format="JPEG")

sample_df.rdd.foreach(consume_row)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually we found the problem in one of the variables used within the consume_row function which was not passed as parameter. Your solution works but recently Databricks and Azure recommend another way of connecting the cluster with the storages (via credentials): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/connect/storage/aad-storage-service-principal

Comment: yeah you did not provided you `consume_row` function and i have also mentioned about `Oauth` that is the documentation you provided.